# Multi-operator Calculator With C

Tags: c, if-statement, switch-statement, calculator

I want to make a calculator which takes 3+4/4*6 kinda input and I need to write it in C programming. I take numbers and operations separately from user, then I put numbers and operators to separate arrays. Then I wanted to loop through arrays respectively to do operations -I know operator priority is not considered- but It is not giving me correct result at all. To determine opeators, first I used switch case then tried If statement but both of them gave wrong results. I am gonna share both of them. How I can re-arrange this code to get correct result ?

By correct result I mean e.g 3+4/1*8 = 56

Comment: You want `number_in` and `operator_in` to be of type `int` and `char`, not `int *` and `char *`: They are numbers, not pointers. (But when you `scanf` your input, you make pointers to them with `&`, so that `scanf` can give a value to tese numbers through them.)

Comment: You really should compile with warnings on. For example, your `ops[x]` are integers, but you compare them to strings. Replace the double quotes with single quotes -- in C, single quotes enclose characters. You should probably also revise your indexing in the actual calculation loop.

Comment: @MOehm When I remove pointer * from both number_in and operator_in, and & from "scanf"s of them, the code messed up :( It did not work

Comment: @MOehm Fixed double quotes thank you

Comment: Well, you should try to understand what these operators do. Randomly adding and removing `*`s and `&`s until the compiler shuts up is usualy not a good strategy for programming. Also "It did not work" is not a good description of an error. What did not work? Did the compiler complain? Did the program crash? Did it give wrong results?

Comment: @MOehm When I started writing this code I did not use any pointer and It gave me the place of the number I wanted. This is why I am using pointer for them and by "It did not work" I mean when I enter 2*5*5 It gives 1 as  a result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many problems with your program. You can learn about some of them when you enable warnings.

**Scanning the input**: Your data input looks like this:

```
int *number_in;

scanf("%d",&number_in);
```

That's not correct. Your input is a whole number, an `int`, not a pointer to an `int`.

```
int number_in;
```

When you read the input, the scanning function must be able to modify `number_in`. One way would be to return the scanned number, but scanf can read multiple inputs, so it chose to return a value that tells you whether the scanning was successful. So `scanf` must store the scanned data by other means: You must pass a pointer to the data you want to scan. The operator `&number_in` creates such a pointer:

```
scanf("%d", &number_in);      // like above, but now on a correct number_in
```

You should also check the result, which would be 1 for "1 item read", 0 for "nothing read" ot `EOF` for "end of input", for example when the user hits Ctrl-D or Ctrl-Z. "Nothing read" means that there is input, but it can't be converted to a number, for example "four". In that case, the *next* `scanf` starts before the unrecognized input, which will probably trip up your syntax.

**Strings versus characters**: C distinguishes between single and double quotation marks. Double quotations marks enclose strings, that is pointers to the first character of an array of characters. You don't use them in your program.

Instead, you work with characters. The notation `'+'` means the character code of the plus sign. In ASCII that's 43.

**Calculation**: There is also a problem with how you calculate your result. You have two independent arrays, one for numbers, one for operators. It is clear that the index `2 * loop` can go out of bounds. The index `2*loop -1` will go out of bounds on the first number. That's bad.

Another problem is that you always operate on two adjacent numbers, but that's not what you want. For example, if your input is `2*3+1`, you first calculate 2 × 3, which is okay, and then you calculate 3 + 1, which isn't okay: You want to calculate 6 + 1 here.

So for example:

```
    8 * 3 / 4 + 5
       24 / 4 + 5
            6 + 5
               11 == result!
```

You loop should look something like this:

```
result = numbers[0];
        
for(loop = 1; loop < number_entry;loop++){
    switch (ops[loop -1]) {
    case '+':   result = result + numbers[loop]; break;
    case '-':   result = result - numbers[loop]; break;
    case '*':   result = result * numbers[loop]; break;
    case '/':   if (numbers[loop] == 0) {
                    puts("Division by zero!");
                    exit(1);
                }            
                result = result / numbers[loop]; break;
    default:    printf("Bad operator '%d'.\n", ops[loop -1]);
    }        
}
```

So, please turn on warnings. They'll tell you about simple errors like type mismatches or mismatches between `scanf`/`printf` format specifiers and data.

Then try to identify algorithmical problems by stepping through the code – in a debugger, with additional `printf`s or with a pencil on a printout.